# Xcode Cocoa App with GLFW3 and C++

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa, opengl, glfw

here's what my current workflow is:

1. Start new project
2. Select OSX->Cocoa Application
3. Give it a project name, location etc
4. Delete the following files:

   - AppDelegate.h
   - AppDelegate.m
   - Assets.xcassets
   - MainMenu.xib
5. Rename main.m to main.cpp (and change it's contents to a C++)
6. Add OpenGL and GLFW3 to 'Link With Libraries' section of Build Phases
7. Add /usr/local/include to 'Header Search Paths' in Build Settings
8. Add a 'Copy Files' Build Phase and copy the GLFW3 library (unsigned)
9. Add a 'Run Script' Build Phase to fix location of GLFW3 and sign it

The reason I do this is because it produces an app bundle that I can give to other OSX users who run it just like any other app.

This process works fine, however after doing this a dozen or so times over the past week I am finding it very tedious.

My question is, what is the best way to automate this? I tried cloning the Xcode OSX Cocoa Application template and tweaking that... So far all I've figured out is how to add the OpenGL framework automatically.

Comment: Zip-up the project when you've done all that and unpack it to create a new project each time.

Comment: Well that's a clever idea.  I suppose it might involve renaming some things but I can definitely see it saving time over what I was doing.  Thanks!